# Applying filter on table rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Mid     TemplateId  FilterName      MappingValue
-----   ----------  -------------   --------------
1       1            JobCode           DC123
2       1            ServiceType       Paid
3       1            SegmentType       New
4       2            JobCode           DC123
5       2            SegmentType       New
6       3            ServiceType       Paid
```

I am writing a stored procedure to fetch data from above table.

The input parameters are:

```
JobCode, ServiceType, SegmentType
```

I want to fetch a unique `templateId` from above table if any record found for above combination, if not, it should return `templateId` for `JobCode` and `ServiceType`, and if this is also not found the it should look for `SegmentType`.

Example:

- If `JobCode = DC123`, `ServiceType = Paid` and `SegmentType = New`, then the code should return `TemplateId = 1`
- If `JobCode = DC123`, `ServiceType = Free` and `SegmentType = New`, the code should return `TemplateId = 2`
- If `JobCode = DC123`, `ServiceType = Paid` and `SegmentType = Old`, the code should return `TemplateId = 3`

Comment: can you show us your stored procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an aggregation query which you may use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_yourproc]
    @jobCode varchar(100),
    @serviceType varchar(100),
    @segmentType varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @templateId int

    SET @templateId = (SELECT TemplateId FROM yourTable GROUP BY TemplateId
        HAVING
            (MAX(CASE WHEN FilterName = 'JobCode'     THEN MappingValue END) = @jobCode OR
             @jobCode IS NULL) AND
            (MAX(CASE WHEN FilterName = 'ServiceType' THEN MappingValue END) = @serviceType OR
             @serviceType IS NULL) AND
            (MAX(CASE WHEN FilterName = 'SegmentType' THEN MappingValue END) = @segmentType OR
             @segmentType IS NULL);

    -- do something with the @templateId

END
```

In the context of a stored proc, you might not want to check all three filter names.  In this case, I treat a `NULL` input parameter as being valid, which means that any of the three inputs can be omitted, if desired.